# Different color for tags in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, colors, tags

So, I'm trying to give a certain tag a specific color in the front-end.

Let's say I have these two tags: private and business. I want the private tag to have a yellow color and the business tag to have a blue color.

I echo the tags with this code:

```
<?php
    $posttags = get_the_tags();
     if ($posttags) {
      foreach($posttags as $tag) {
       echo $tag->name . ' ';
      }
     }
   ?>
```

How can I give them the color I want, to be displayed at the front-end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may check for tag name and apply css to change the color, hope this helps

```
$post_tags = get_the_tags();
    if ( $post_tags ) {
    foreach( $post_tags as $tag) :
        if ( $tag->name === 'private' ) :
    ?>
    <span style="color:#FFFF00;"><?php echo $tag->name; ?></span>

    <?php
        elseif ( $tag->name === 'business' ) :
    ?>

     <span style="color:#0000FF;"><?php echo $tag->name; ?></span>

    <?php
        else :
        // Post has neither tag, do nothing.
        endif; 
    endforeach;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I've replaced the names for the right ones. Yet it doesn't seem to echo the tags with this code.

Comment: Never mind, apparently Wordpress is Case sensitive. It worked! Thankyou!